# random between variables in C++?

Tags: c++, random, boolean

First of all, I am still a beginner at learning programming. So please pardon me!

If i were to have 4 boolean values, let's say

```
a[0] = true
a[1] = false
a[2] = false
a[3] = true
```

and I were to randomize ONLY true values, how am I suppose to random them?

For example, since a[0] and a[3] is true, I can only random number 0 **OR** 3. but random goes something like this

```
int random = rand() % 4 + 0;
```

So it will random from range 0 **TO** 3. How am I suppose to do that with only true values? Please guide me along, thank you!

Comment: "How am I suppose to do that with only true values?" - makes no sense, since output will always be 'True'

Comment: If I understand correctly:  you're not trying to choose a boolean, you're trying to choose a number, and the booleans indicate that 0 and 3 are the only numbers that are eligible to be chosen.

Comment: The question is very unclear. Please do give a detailed example of desired behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this specific case where there are only two possible values to be chosen, you can choose a random number and check whether it's even or odd:

```
int random = (rand() % 2) ? 0 : 3;
```

More generally, you can make a list of the values that are eligible to be chosen, and then choose a random element from that list:

```
std::vector<int> choices = { 0, 3, 9, 42 };
int random = choices[rand() % choices.size()];
```

Comment: Except that `%` is biased, and also uses the lowest bits of the value which in many cases are the ones with the worst randomness properties.

Comment: And C++11 has better random generators than `rand()` anyway.  But that's tangential to the actual question, and I didn't want to make things unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: Hi @Wyzard I am unable to make a list of values that are eligible to be chosen in this scenario because it is forever changing, one instance it might be a[0] = true, a[1] = false , a[2] = true and a[3] = true the other instance all might be false. As mentioned, if the first instance is the case, I can only randomize a[0], a[2] and a[3] excluding a[1] false.

Comment: That just means you need to create a new list of choices each time.  Start with an empty vector and `push_back` each value that should be eligible.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you only want to pick an index where the value is true.

Two ways to do it:

- make an array with just the true index numbers and pick a random there
- keep randomizing you existing one until you get the true value (not really nice)

So, in the first case you'd have something like:

```
b[0] = 0;
b[1] = 3;
```

and then, since there are 2 such elements, you'd modify your randomizer to:

```
int random = rand() % 2;
```

Comment: Hi Shomz, 

If your b[0] = true , and b[1] = false, b[2] = true. How are you be able to randomize 0 OR 2 only without including 1 ?

Comment: Hi, my `b` values can't be false, in fact they are integers referring to the true `a` values (which are 0 and 3, that's why my `b` is `[0,3]`). It's basically an extension of your original code - the same concept that Wyzard suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I managed to cook together. The program loops through the bool array and adds all indices that are true to a temporary array.

```
#include <vector>
#define ARRAY_SIZE 4

int main( char** argv, int argc )
{
    bool a[ ARRAY_SIZE ] = { true, false, false, true };

    std::vector< int > Available;
    for ( int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i )
        if ( a[ i ] )
            Available.push_back( i );

    int random = Available[ rand() % static_cast< int >( Available.size() ) ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out the correct answer is to construct a list of of eligible values and pick randomly from that list:

```
size_t randomInt(size_t min, size_t max) {
  static std::random_device rd;
  static std::mt19937 eng(rd());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> dist(min,max);
  return dist(eng);
}

int a[] = {true, false, false, true};

std::vector<int> eligible;
for(size_t i = 0u; i != 4u; ++i) {
  if(a[i])
    eligible.push_back(i);
}

auto random = eligible[randomInt(0u, eligible.size() - 1u)];
```

But if, for some reason it is not possible to create a list of eligible values upfront, it is interesting to know that [you can select randomly from a sequence of unknown length](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201208/selecting_randomly_from_an_unknown_sequence.html). So you could pick an item from the array in a single pass if you really need to:

```
size_t n = 0u;
size_t random = 0u;
for(size_t i = 0u; i != 4u; ++i) {
  if (a[i]) {
    if (randomInt(0u, n) == 0)
      random = i;
    ++n;
  }  
}
```